# How to Use WinSetState function from the AutoIT Library with C#

Tags: c#, .net, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am wondering how to provide the third parameter for this function being I cannot find any documentation or am looking at the documentation incorrectly.

```
  string windowTitle = "None Of Your Business";

   AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3(); // auto it object

   auto.WinSetState(windowTitle, "", 1); //function I am trying to call
```

The third parameter is where I have dubbed in the number 1, the data type is integer but the documentation when using AutoIt Scite IDE says this:

> Parameters title  The title/hWnd/class of the window to change the
>   state. See Title special definition. text The text of the window to
>   change the state. See Text special definition. flag   The "show" flag of
>   the executed program:

- > ```
  > @SW_HIDE = Hide window
  > @SW_SHOW = Shows a previously hidden window
  > @SW_MINIMIZE = Minimize window
  > @SW_MAXIMIZE = Maximize window
  > @SW_RESTORE = Undoes a window minimization or maximization
  > @SW_DISABLE = Disables the window
  > @SW_ENABLE = Enables the window Return Value Success:  1. Failure: 0 if the window is not found.
  > ```

Reference:
       https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm

I am attempting to use the @SW_MAXIMIZE option, how would I supply this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that you just need to reference the autoit object created like below:

```
auto.WinSetState(gameTitle, "", auto.SW_MAXIMIZE);
```